# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

Code PHP

```
    <p>'
 if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {
 echo '<p><b>Name: </b>'.$Show["Name6"].' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>'.$Show["Post6"];
 }'</p>

   </div>';
  }     
  ?>
```

I need help To correct this error

Comment: Show full code, please.

Comment: Please use underscore_case for variable names. It's better!

Comment: @xfix Can you justify that? It's reasonable in sql for obvious reasons but underscore_case is way less common than camelCase and PascalCase in "normal" code.

Comment: @Jonast92 Probably he just wanted to say that every programmer has its own style. But i would use the most common standard so other programmers can read my code fast and easy.

Comment: @Jonast92: It just makes sense for me. PHP took OOP parts from Java (with all its camel case), but the procedural parts from Perl use underscores (just look at builtin functions). While I agree this is inconsistent (it's not that PHP is consistent), it's probably the easiest way to stay sane in PHP (but whatever you do, don't start variables with uppercase letters (nobody does that in PHP), or variables like `$longArgs_noVars` that PHP-FIG suggests). Then again, I use camelCase for object properties (it's just declarator which just uses variable syntax, but real accessing syntax uses `->`)...

Answer (score 1):

Use like.

```
 <?php
 echo '<p>';
 if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {
 echo '<p><b>Name: </b>'.$Show["Name6"].' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>'.$Show["Post6"];
 }
  echo'</p></div>';
  }     
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo '<p>';

if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {
    echo '<p><b>Name: </b>' . $Show["Name6"] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>'.$Show["Post6"];
}

echo '</p></div>';  
?>
```

Try to use like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code is messed up. Try to fix it like this.

```
 <?php
 echo '<p>';
 if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {
 echo '<p><b>Name: </b>'.$Show["Name6"].' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>'.$Show["Post6"];
 }
echo '</p>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

***This should work***

```
<?php
echo '<p>';
if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {
    echo '<p><b>Name: </b>'.$Show["Name6"].' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>'.$Show["Post6"];
}
echo '</p></div>';
?>
```

The HTML will most likely not be "correct" but the code will execute.

***Why?***

Your code is simply invalid.

This, for example

```
<p>'
if
```

Has no proper meaning.

Is

```
<p>'
```

suppose to be a string? You need to finish all statements with a semicolon and each string much start with a ' or a ", indicating the beginning of a string.

And this

```
}'</p>

</div>';
```

will not echo anything since you're missing the echo keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way:

```
<?php
  echo "<div><p>";

 if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {

echo <<< END
<p><b>Name: </b>{$Show['Name6']}&nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>{$Show['Post6']}
END;

  }     

echo "</p></div>";
?>
```

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html

Answer (score -1):

If you are using php within html. You should use php syntax when you are using php in html
like :

```
 <p>'
 <?php if($Show['Name6'] != NULL) {
 echo '<p><b>Name: </b>'.$Show["Name6"].' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Post : </b>'.$Show["Post6"];
 } ?>'</p>

   </div>';
  }     
  ?>
```

As you haven't posted full code. so try adjusting php syntax.
Hope this helps.

Comment: have you tried your code before answering?